# Listview Disable Items Android:

Tags: android

I've listView with multiple row.
Row componets 1.TextView, 2.CheckedTextView.
I want to disable all the items in that listVIew One of my listView it's working fine in other listView it's working. I've use the following method to do my work.

```
protected void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
        int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            view.setEnabled(enabled);
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** 
The listView is disabled in my case too. But the problem is it is able too click the checkedTextview.
I've call this `enableDisableViewGroup` method from listView onScroll method.

Comment: try to disable your views in getView() method after setting data in it.

Comment: I am not using getView() method here. I just add data using Simpleadapter.

Comment: can you post complete code.. I think that will help us.